# XSLT - concatenating values to existing one

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML:

[image]

I would like **id** to be the concatenation of subname + subname2. Example: For the first one id would be: ThinkVision, the second one: LenovoMind

Is this achievable via xsl:for-each ?

I tried using the following xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="/records/record/customList/customBucket[fn:lower-case(customName)='id']/customValue/text()">
    <xsl:for-each select="/records/record/customList">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(customBucket[fn:lower-case(customName)='subname']/customValue/text(),customBucket[fn:lower-case(customName)='subname2']/customValue/text())"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But I get the concatenation of every record instead of the current one:

[image]

SAMPLE XML : `<records>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Think</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Vision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Lenovo</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Mind</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Think</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Vision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Mapped</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Safe</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Sony</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>DCO</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
</records>`

expected output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
<record>
    <customList>
        <customBucket>
            <customName>id</customName>
            <customValue>ThinkVision</customValue>
        </customBucket>
        <customBucket>
            <customName>subname</customName>
            <customValue>Think</customValue>
        </customBucket>
        <customBucket>
            <customName>subname2</customName>
            <customValue>Vision</customValue>
        </customBucket>
    </customList>
</record>
<record>
    <customList>
        <customBucket>
            <customName>id</customName>
            <customValue>LenovoMind</customValue>
        </customBucket>
        <customBucket>
            <customName>subname</customName>
            <customValue>Lenovo</customValue>
        </customBucket>
        <customBucket>
            <customName>subname2</customName>
            <customValue>Mind</customValue>
        </customBucket>
    </customList>
</record>
</records>
```

==

SCENARIO # 2

INPUT:

```
<records>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Think</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Vision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Lenovo</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Mind</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Think</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Vision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Mapped</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Safe</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Sony</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>DCO</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
</records>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
<records>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>ThinkVision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Think</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Vision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>LenovoMind</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Lenovo</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Mind</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>ThinkVision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Think</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Vision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>MappedSafe</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Mapped</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Safe</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>SonyDCO</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Sony</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>DCO</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
</records>
```

Basically instead of overwriting the 'id' the idea here is to create a new node called 'newid' with the same logic as the scenario 1:  concatenation of subname + subname2.

[image]

SCENARIO 2.1

EXPECTED OUTPUT (same as scenario 2, but with the original id renamed)

I added the following code but it doesn't rename the id.

```
<xsl:param name="normRenamedID" select="'id_renamed'"/>

    <!-- Rename clientPortfolioID to RM_clientPortfolioID-->
    <xsl:template match="/customBucket[fn:lower-case(customName)='clientportfolioid']/customName/text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$normRenamedID"/>
    </xsl:template>


<records>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id_renamed</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>ThinkVision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Think</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Vision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id_renamed</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>LenovoMind</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Lenovo</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Mind</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id_renamed</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>ThinkVision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Think</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Vision</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id_renamed</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>MappedSafe</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Mapped</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>Safe</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
    <record>
        <customList>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>id_renamed</customName>
                <customValue>default</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>newid</customName>
                <customValue>SonyDCO</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname</customName>
                <customValue>Sony</customValue>
            </customBucket>
            <customBucket>
                <customName>subname2</customName>
                <customValue>DCO</customValue>
            </customBucket>
        </customList>
    </record>
</records>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a **reproducible** example - including the XML input and the expected output, both  **as code**, not as picture - see:[mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/records/record/customList">
```

you are selecting **all** `customList` elements, starting from the `/`root node. Your current context plays no role here.

To get the result you're looking for, try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="customBucket[customName='id']/customValue">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../customBucket[customName='subname']/customValue" />
        <xsl:value-of select="../../customBucket[customName='subname2']/customValue" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

For your added scenario, change the 2nd template to:

```
<xsl:template match="customBucket[customName='id']">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <customBucket>
        <customName>newid</customName>
        <customValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="../customBucket[customName='subname']/customValue" />
            <xsl:value-of select="../customBucket[customName='subname2']/customValue" />
        </customValue>
    </customBucket>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added 2:

For your additional scenario, change the 2nd template to:

```
<xsl:template match="customBucket[customName='id']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <customName>
            <xsl:value-of select="$normRenamedID" />
        </customName>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="customValue"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <customBucket>
        <customName>newid</customName>
        <customValue>
            <xsl:value-of select="../customBucket[customName='subname']/customValue" />
            <xsl:value-of select="../customBucket[customName='subname2']/customValue" />
        </customValue>
    </customBucket>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hey Michael, taking into consideration the same example as above, is it possible instead of copying the value to a existing "customValue" to instead create a brand new node under customBucket, like an id2 for example.

Comment: Not sure I understand the requirement; could you edit your question and add the new expected result?

Comment: @JorgeFlores See the addition to my post.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.

Comment: last question about this. Your last solution worked flawlessly, however I tried renaming the id (as shown on the last picture) and it doesn't do anything.  Can you assess if it is doable?

Comment: If you want to change something, then you cannot be copying it. See above.